# Specifying a FilterSet for Django-rest-framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

The tutorial said:

```
class ProductFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    min_price = django_filters.NumberFilter(lookup_type='gte')
    max_price = django_filters.NumberFilter(lookup_type='lte')
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['category', 'in_stock', 'min_price', 'max_price']
```

but when I try to do this, I get an error:

`FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword u'min_price' into field. Choices are: cantidad, datetime, enlace, id, id_fila, nivel`

`min_price` is not in my models, but I need to create a new parameter. (it is an example)
really I need to filter dates.

Answer (score 4):

See the [django-filter documentation](https://django-filter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/filters.html#name).

Since your `min_price` and `max_price` filters don't have the same name as the model field they refer too, you need to provide the `name` argument.

```
class ProductFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    min_price = django_filters.NumberFilter(name='price', lookup_type='gte')
    max_price = django_filters.NumberFilter(name='price', lookup_type='lte')
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['category', 'in_stock', 'min_price', 'max_price']
```

Comment: This works with django-filter. But what about `OrderingFilter`? When I use `order_by = ('-name',)` in `FilterSet`, it gives me the same error. Here is the field:

`name = django_filters.CharFilter(name='full_name')`